# Java, Android - Start a python flask server on localhost

Tags: java, python, android, flask

I was looking at the possible ways to use my python function on android. And now saw this-- https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/169/ . It explains how I can 'turn my python script into a website' . This method is useful-- people will run it on their browser. But it's not useful for me. My project needs web scraping and the site(s) I scrape can block my server's IP if I post too many requests. Now, this is my idea-- I will write a java android program to start the flask webapp on localhost when my app starts and integrate a web viewer into the app to view the webapp on localhost. The only thing that I want to know is, starting the server on localhost is possible with java or not.

Comment: Are you saying you would like to start a web-server on the phone/device that has downloaded and is running your app?  Do you mean to ***have them make the connections*** from ***their phone*** so that you don't run into the "making too many connections" problem?  Is that it?  I don't quite get the question so well...

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to run the server on the android phone.

Comment: Well, maybe you should "re-think" this a little bit...  I don't quite get why an additional "web-server" makes any difference at all.  I am choosing not to provide a "real answer" to this question, because I don't do **Android Java** (for devices, although I do a lot of **Java**)...  ***BUT*** I do know that a **Java App** can make outgoing connections from any device, which leads me to ask you:  Why would configuring any web-server on their device make any difference - if the limiting factor is how many HTTP requests are being made?

Comment: If the App on the user's device makes the connections, likely that is the best you can do - other than paying for "***multiple*** IP Addresses" so you can make lots of requests to  a web-server that has a `Bot Blocker`.  **NOTE:** `Bot-Blockers` like to check for multiple requests from the same IP Address over and over again...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. Instead, you can have it as an API and then make requests whenever you need it.